# How to convert script hash to base58 address?

Tags: address, base58

For example :

take a look at this  **37d1d453311ea5682cdb31468826178db15fa731722a5dbb09525ea901f1c41c** scripthash.

I need help converting it to base58 address.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your choice using [**bitcoin explorer**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki) (bx):

`echo 37d1d453311ea5682cdb31468826178db15fa731722a5dbb09525ea901f1c41c | bx ec-to-public | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx base58check-encode -v 5`

**32BcK7C6FBCzzyB617gwTQuaLdbQufuAcc**

`% echo 37d1d453311ea5682cdb31468826178db15fa731722a5dbb09525ea901f1c41c | bx ec-to-public | bx bitcoin160 | bx base58check-encode -v 5`

**32BcK7C6FBCzzyB617gwTQuaLdbQufuAcc**

`% echo 37d1d453311ea5682cdb31468826178db15fa731722a5dbb09525ea901f1c41c | bx ec-to-public | bx ec-to-address -v 5`

**32BcK7C6FBCzzyB617gwTQuaLdbQufuAcc**

Comment: Hello Skaht, the expected result looks like a multisig address but that script belongs to non multisig address. Thanks.

Comment: Bitcoin P2SH and BIP 49 P2WPKH-nested-in-P2SH addresses both start with the number 3. Take a look at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/chainparams.cpp#L132 to see why the version is set to 5.  Also look at column 5 of this [**Table**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table).

Comment: To provide more context, it would not hurt to share the original script that was encoded and hashed to 37d1d453311ea5682cdb31468826178db15fa731722a5dbb09525ea901f1c41c.  I'm not 100% certain I properly answered your question.

Comment: The answer might be simpler:
```% echo 37d1d453311ea5682cdb31468826178db15fa731722a5dbb09525ea901f1c41c | bx bitcoin160 | bx address-encode -v 5```

**3GRerFiaihoo7mwMBix6Xojtff46HBNtnB**

Comment: Or: ```% echo 37d1d453311ea5682cdb31468826178db15fa731722a5dbb09525ea901f1c41c | bx ripemd160 | bx address-encode -v 5``` This is most likely the answer without knowing more.
**3JSbrUCtDBzWGVWjZ5rFDxBh2Kzhszor9U**

Comment: Hello Skaht, thank you very much for understanding the issue. Heres an example: **scripthash**: 47e414636b2d5675ce1ef1459775792d9bee689f0b97b0a43f92a69cc3db4845  **address** : 19pTZUvpBt5EXPJSVjp56YA6AzUazNFGdi , i'm still trying to get that from your steps. :D

Comment: What is the script before it gets hashed?